# Conditional Copy of Middle Name if first and last names match

Tags: excel, vba

I'm very new at this. I've searched the site and haven't found an answer.

I have two lists of names, one is in a specific order, that I'd like to not disturb, and the other is in alphabetical order.

Example of the two lists is below. The one on the left is alphabetical order, and the other is arranged due to performance on a test. There are several hundred names.

```
(Last)      (First)     (Middle)   ...     (Last)       (First)    (M.I.)

A1          B1           C1     ...     I1           J1        K1

Pennyworth  Alfred      Johnathan   ... Maryfellow   Jeannine   S.
```

I need a program to search/compare the copy specific info in the two.

Here's what I think it needs to do, I just don't know how to tell the computer to do it: Search columns A and B, if A and B equal any of I and J, copy the C in the matching alphabetical to the corresponding K. Continue to next name. I know that's probably backwards, I'm just trying to make the explanation simple. Essentially I need to computer to look through the alphabetical names, and copy the middle name, in full, to the K column of the correct person.

Let me know if you need additional information.

Comment: that's the thing, I have very little coding experience, so I have nothing already created.

Comment: This is not a code writing service.  If you need a code writing service, my current contract rate is $60/hr for VBA.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do this via VBA. You can do it via a vlookup. You will need to do some changes before it can be done though. You will need to insert a column before column C which will consist of `=B1&A1` (assuming the lists start at A1. If there is titles then change to `=B2&A1` then drag that all the way down so the firstnames and the last names are merged. Then in K1 put `=vlookup(J1&I1,C:D,2,0)` This will then give the middle name if there is any matches

Answer (score 0):

The following will work, but it assumes there are no cases where the first name / last name combination is repeated for different middle names. If you need to account for that scenario with your data, let me know. Using VBA has the advantage of not requiring the adjustment of your layout as suggested.

```
Sub GetMiddleNames()

    Dim i1 As Long, i2 As Long, c As Long
    Dim v1 As Variant, v2 As Variant, v3 As Variant

    v1 = [a1].CurrentRegion
    With Range("i1"): v2 = .Resize(.CurrentRegion.Rows.Count, 2): End With
    c = UBound(v2)
    v3 = [k1].Resize(c)

    For i2 = 1 To c
        For i1 = 1 To UBound(v1)
            If v1(i1, 1) = v2(i2, 1) Then
                If v1(i1, 2) = v2(i2, 2) Then
                    v3(i2, 1) = v1(i1, 3)
                End If
            End If
        Next
    Next

    [k1].Resize(c) = v3

End Sub
```